# Streamlit Markdown

Tags: python, markdown, streamlit

I am using markdown and try to color words like it says in the streamlit documentation but it won't work, any can help me please ?

```
import streamlit as st
st.markdown("Text can be :blue[azul], but also :orange[laranja]. And of course it can be 
:red[red]. And :green[verde]. And look at this :violet[violeta]!")
```

it is all black.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Where do you see the resulting text?

Comment: in the Edge browser, I will upload a image.

Comment: theres a picture there now as you can see it wont show colors only if I use Html/css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensure that have streamlit updated (1.16.0) and try:

```
st.markdown("This text is :red[colored red], and this is **:blue[colored]** and bold.")
```

Comment: I had 1.11, it only works on 1.16. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```py
st.markdown(
    'This will print <span style="color:blue;"> blue text </span>',
    unsafe_allow_html=True
)
```